# Finite polynomial maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I am considering a map from $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ where $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$.

I am unsure how to show whether this is finite or not, I can not see how to relate this to an integral extension.

I am looking for guidance on this question so as I can attempt similar ones too.

Comment: A map is proper if and only if it is proper and quasi-finite. The latter means that fibers over any point is finite. In your map the fiber over the origin is infinite (over an infinite field) and thus the map is not finite.

Comment: The extension of rings to consider is $k[x, xy] \subseteq k[x,y]$ or more precisely, the map $k[s,t] \to k[x,y]$ given by $s \mapsto x, t \mapsto xy$.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your help! Both comments have helped a lot. Sorry if this is a simple question but @Quasicoherent following your hint, the map is infinite because $xy$ is not integral over $k[x,y]$?

Comment: I think you've got it a bit backwards: $xy \in k[x,y]$, so it's certainly integral over $k[x,y]$. But you're right that it's $xy$ that causes the problem. Try to show that $y$ is not integral over $k[x,xy]$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I see the mistake I made now in my comment.